# How to get value of one variable based on another variable in r?

Tags: r, netcdf

For a netcdf file while includes precipitation values at many grid cells. The grid cells are represented by latitude and longitude. How to get the precipitation value at a specific grid, say, latitude and longitude? Thanks.
For example, I used the code to open the file:

```
library('ncdf4')
precip.nc = nc_open('obs.pr.nc')
```

When I typed precip.nc, it shows three variables:

```
float longitude_bnds
float latitude_bnds
float pr
```

How to open the pr at a specific longitude_bnds and latitude_bnds?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using ncdf4?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ncdf4

Comment: I'm not familiar. what does `ncvar_get(precip.nc)` show you

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280104/how-to-take-a-subset-from-a-netcdf-file-using-latitude-longitude-boundaries-in-r) would help

Comment: Seems it just shows all precipitation values, but I don't know which one is from which position.

Comment: I highly suggest using the `raster` package, it's just so much easier.